# Histogram in Bokeh charts takes a looong time

Tags: matplotlib, bokeh

I am trying to move from matplotlib to bokeh. However, I am finding some annoying features. Last I encountered was that it took several minutes to make an histogram of about 1.5M entries - it would have taken a fraction of a second with Matplotlib. Is that normal? And if so, what's the reason?

```
from bokeh.charts import Histogram, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
output_notebook()
jd1 = pd.read_csv("somefile.csv")
p = Histogram(jd1['QTY'], bins=50)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure offhand what might be going on with `Histogram` in your case. Without the data file it's impossible to try and reproduce or debug. But in any case `bokeh.charts` does not really have a maintainer at the moment, so I would actually just recommend using `bokeh.plotting` to create your historgam. The `bokeh.plotting` API is stable (for several years now) and extensively documented. It's a few more lines of code but not many:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

output_notebook()

# synthesize example data
measured = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 1000)

hist, edges = np.histogram(measured, density=True, bins=50)

p = figure(title="Normal Distribution (μ=0, σ=0.5)")
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], line_color=None)

show(p)
```

[image]

As you can see that takes (on my laptop) ~half a second for a 10 million point histogram, including generating synthetic data and binning it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the original dataset. It does not answer my literal questio, but does answer the underlying one here: what is the workaround for having a histogram with the plotting API? I will rephrase the question. Thanks a lot! - I just wish I knew this a couple of hours earlier :(